# Passing parameter form jsp to servlet to jsp and then to another servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Is there a way to pass a parameter to a servlet going through another jsp and then to another servlet 
like 
**jsp**---*parameter*--->**servlet**(using getParameter())---*parameter*--->**jsp**---*parameter*--->**servlet**(is there a way to get the parameter here)

The program that am working on is to pass the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use [HTTPsession](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).

> Provides a way to identify a user across more than one page request or visit to a Web site and to store information about that user.
>   The servlet container uses this interface to create a session between an HTTP client and an HTTP server. The session persists for a specified time period, across more than one connection or page request from the user. A session usually corresponds to one user, who may visit a site many times. The server can maintain a session in many ways such as using cookies or rewriting URLs.

Setting

```
Session session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("username", username);
```

getting it back

```
String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
```